# Perl send command result into array and create choice menu

Tags: arrays, perl, menu, output

I must put the processing of the result from a scan of surrounding wifi networks into a nicely presented list, from which one can just pick up the network they want to connect to, enter wifi key and get connected.

I'm quite new to Perl and I must admit that I've already gone through numerous tutorials and forums, yet I still have great trouble figuring out how to get the proper syntax regarding the handling of arrays and hashes.

Here's where I stopped in my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $result =  `iwlist wlan1 scan`;

my @TABLE;

my ($line, $cell, $address, $channel, $freq, $qty, $qty1, $qty2, $encrypt, $sid, $group);

my $cpt = 1;

my @tab = split(/\n/, $result);

foreach $line (@tab)
{
    $line =~ s/^\s+//;

        if  ($line =~ /Cell/) 
        {
            $line =~ /Cell (\d\d)/;
            $cell = $1;
                        }               

        if  ($line =~ /Address/)
        {
            $line =~ /Address: (.*)/;
            $address = $1;                  
        }

        if  ($line =~ /^Channel/)
        {
            $line =~ /Channel:(\d+)/;
            $channel = $1;                              
        }

        if  ($line =~ /Frequency/)
        {
            $line =~ /Frequency:(\d\.\d\d\d) GHz/;
            $freq = $1;             
        }

        if  ($line =~ /Quality/)
        {
            $line =~ /Quality=(\d\d)\/(\d\d)/;
            $qty1 = $1;
            $qty2 = $2;             
        }

        if  ($line =~ /Encryption/)
        {
            $line =~ /Encryption key:(.*)/;
            $encrypt = $1;              
        }

        if  ($line =~ /ESSID/)
        {
            $line =~ /ESSID:(.*)/;
            $sid = $1;              
        }

        if  ($line =~ /Group/)
        {
            $line =~ /[^Cipher]/;
            $group = $1;                
        }

($cpt, $cell, $address, $channel, $freq, $qty1, $qty2, $encrypt, $sid, $group) = @TABLE;

foreach $line (@TABLE)
{
print $line;
}

}


#print "Choisissez le réseau auquel vous voulez vous connecter : ";
#my $choice = <>;
#chomp $choice;

#if ($choice = $cell)
#{
#   print "Entrez la clé wifi : "
#   my $key = <>;
#   chomp $key;

#   `iwconfig eth0 $sid $key`;
#   `dhcpcd eth0`;
#}

#else
#   print "Numéro de réseau invalide."
#   exit(0);

#   foreach my $key (sort keys %TABLE)
#   {
#           print 'key=$key '. $TABLE{$key}{'Cell'}."\n";
#   }
```

Any help would be **greatly** appreciated!

Comment: Sorry about that. I just need help to send the cleansed output (after the series of 'if') into a table, so that I get a result like that:

Cell 01 - Address: 40:5A:9B:E1:A0:E6, Channel: 6, Quality=36/70, Encryption key: on, ESSID:"CYPE France"

Comment: You are probably looking for a combination of `push` and array references or hash references so that you could do something like this: `push @TABLE, [$cell, $address, $channel, $freq, $qty1, $qty2, $encrypt, $sid, $group];` Later you would `print "@$_\n" foreach @TABLE;`  Beware, though, there are many other problems, such as `$group` being assigned `$1` without any capturing, and `[^Cipher]` is probably not what you think.  I suggest reading `perldoc perlintro`, `perldoc perlreftut`, and `perldoc perlretut` as well as `perldoc perlsub` for starters.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Yes, there are other problems. It's not finished yet. About group, I forgot to finish by (.*). [^Cipher] is to forget Cipher during the parsing.
No, I haven't read perldoc or perlintro yet. I'm gonna do it. But what would really help me is a way to get this done, so that I can learn from it, instead of losing days trying to understand and guess it.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I have a tutor who forbids me to use push. Yeah, I know... He really, really wants me to do it his way. The problem is that I haven't got around his way yet, and I'm afraid I won't within a short time, for his hasn't enough time to explain things nicely to me. I'm just left with tutorials and forums and,, to tell the truth, I'm really tired not to find out how it works.

Comment: `[^Cipher]` means that the string "A Cipher" would match, because your character class matches any single character that is not one of (C, i, p, h, e, r).  "A" is not one of those characters, so the string matches.  Anyway, SO is here to help you learn to code, not to get your project done quickly.

Comment: If you aren't allowed to use `push` (a silly constraint unless there is a valid reason we don't know about), invert the loop and use `my @TABLE= map {...} @tab;`

Answer (score 1):

```
my $result =  `iwlist wlan1 scan`;

...

my @tab = split(/\n/, $result);
```

That code can all be replaced with:

```
my @tab = `iwlist wlan1 scan`;
```

In fact, I'd probably be tempted to leap straight to:

```
foreach my $line (`iwlist wlan1 scan`)
```

You have a lot of blocks that look like this.

```
if  ($line =~ /Cell/) 
{
    $line =~ /Cell (\d\d)/;
    $cell = $1;
}
```

You can combine the first two lines.

```
if ($line ~ /Cell (\d\d)/) {
    $cell = $1;
}
```

After carefully setting all of your variables like `$cell`, you then overwrite them all with undefined values.

```
($cpt, $cell, $address, $channel, $freq, $qty1, $qty2, $encrypt, $sid, $group) = @TABLE;
```

I think you probably wanted:

```
push @TABLE, [$cpt, $cell, $address, $channel, $freq, $qty1, $qty2, $encrypt, $sid, $group];
```

Or, if you're determined not to use `push()` (which, as others have said, is completely bizarre):

```
$TABLE[@TABLE] =  [$cpt, $cell, $address, $channel, $freq, $qty1, $qty2, $encrypt, $sid, $group];
```

You'll then want to print out something about each network that you have found.

```
foreach (@TABLE) {
  say "$_->[1]"; # The second element (index 1) is the cell
}
```

It's not really clear where you want to go from there. But hopefully that will get you a bit further.

Comment: Thank you very, very much. I've understood your remarks.

Comment: From here, I need to print the table showing the details of each cell on one line at a time, then ask the user which network he wishes to connect to, then ask for the corresponding wifi key.

Comment: Ok. And how do you want to do that? What kind of output device are you using? Is this a terminal window or a web page or what? What problems are you having? Has my code got you any closer? Please answer these questions by editing the information into your original post.